# Start fixed position in determinated position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in Javascript:

```
var  menuPosition = $('.scroll-nav').offset().top;
var  menuPos = 110;

if (menuPosition = menuPos) {
  $('.scroll-nav').addClass('stick-menu');
  $('.fake-nav').removeClass('stick-menu');
}
```

My idea is when the position of the `menuPostion` be in 110px stick the `.scroll-nav`... but when I load the page the code is executed automaticaly.

Any idea?

EDIT

Solution to my question:

```
var distance = $('.scroll-nav').offset().top + 200, //+200 BECAUSE JQUERY OFFSET DONT GET MARGINS AND PADDINGS (+200 is an estimative of my total)
$window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function() {
    if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance ) {
        $('.scroll-nav').addClass('is-sticky');
        $('.fake-nav').removeClass('is-sticky');
    }
    if ( $window.scrollTop() <= distance ) {
        $('.scroll-nav').removeClass('is-sticky');
        $('.fake-nav').addClass('is-sticky');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap this into a function and add event listener on scroll which would fire it when scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to add a class if the menuPos is exactly 110? You can use:

```
$(document).ready(callback)
```

And instead of callback you can write anonymous function that will be executed when the page is loaded. You can attach a function on this item in particular.

You can write and a custom eventListener that will catch a position change on an item:

```
jQuery.fn.onPositionChanged = function (trigger, millis) {
    if (millis == null) millis = 100;
    var o = $(this[0]); // our jquery object
    if (o.length < 1) return o;

    var lastPos = null;
    var lastOff = null;
    setInterval(function () {
        if (o == null || o.length < 1) return o; // abort if element is non existend eny more
        if (lastPos == null) lastPos = o.position();
        if (lastOff == null) lastOff = o.offset();
        var newPos = o.position();
        var newOff = o.offset();
        if (lastPos.top != newPos.top || lastPos.left != newPos.left) {
            $(this).trigger('onPositionChanged', { lastPos: lastPos, newPos: newPos });
            if (typeof (trigger) == "function") trigger(lastPos, newPos);
            lastPos = o.position();
        }
        if (lastOff.top != newOff.top || lastOff.left != newOff.left) {
            $(this).trigger('onOffsetChanged', { lastOff: lastOff, newOff: newOff});
            if (typeof (trigger) == "function") trigger(lastOff, newOff);
            lastOff= o.offset();
        }
    }, millis);

    return o;
};
```

you can trigger this event like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.scroll-nav').onPositionChanged(someFunctionForExample());
}
```

*the condition in the if statement should be with '=='

P.s. I hope I understood your problem right. If I did not. Share some more thoughts on this so we can help

Comment: Sorry man, I think I have explained really bad my question, anyway I got a solution searching in internet!!